# How frequently does the Golang net poller loop?

Tags: go, goroutine, epoll

Golang newbie here. I was reading about golang runtime scheduling. This [blog](https://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/08/performance-without-the-event-loop) mentions that the Go runtime runs a network poller as a separate thread that pools on an epoll instance (for linux) to get the list of goroutines that can be unparked.

This raised a couple of questions for me:

- How frequently does this net poller run?
- How does it notify which goroutines are now ready and can be added to the run queue?
- How does the go runtime ensure that the net poller thread is not starved?

Comment: As far as I know the netpoller runs the undelying os polling interface, for example in linux it uses epoll. That means, that it just sleeps waiting for anything to be ready, and the os notifies it if it can perform io.

Comment: There is no "frequency" with epoll, so the first question doesn't makes sense in its current form, and the other questions are kind of confusing. Maybe this will help: https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2018/08/scheduling-in-go-part1.html. (the mailing list is probably a better place to look for help with the current Go implementation).

Comment: Perhaps I should have phrased it better. What I meant to ask was that if the epoller is simply an event loop, how frequently does that call epoll_wait. Does the call block indefinitely till there is an event. And once epoll_wait does return, is the next epoll_wait instance called immediately